# Apex Language Server Extension not getting activated in Visual studio code - ForceCode: Force Menu

Tags: visualforce-component, force.com, visual, visualstudiocode, forcecode

I have made changes to the JSON setting  like

```
 "salesforcedx-vscode-apex.java.home":"/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_131"
```

but still Force Menu is not getting displayed in the Visual studio code menu.
Unable to connect to any of the orgs also not getting any errors. Even I did not get prompt in browser or output. How to Activate the Apex Language Server Extension. Could you please provide the steps to integrate and get all apex class, Triggers, Components from the Force Code.
[image]

Comment: [ForceCode](https://johnaaronnelson.gitbooks.io/forcecode/content/#configuration) and Salesforce DX are completely different products. Which are you using here?

Comment: I'm using Force code, initially I need to pull the classes, triggers etc from my Org to vs code.. For that I'm using Force code plugin in vs code.

Answer (score 1):

[ForceCode](https://github.com/celador/ForceCode) is a now-unmaintained project that is entirely distinct from Salesforce DX. The Apex Language Server is a third semi-independent piece of functionality, which is used by Salesforce DX to provide IntelliSense code smartness and other functionality. The language server requires Java, but is not used by ForceCode.

The configuration value `"salesforcedx-vscode-apex.java.home"` is not part of ForceCode configuration, and shouldn't have any effect on whether or not you are able to use that plugin successfully.

You should install the ForceCode plugin from the Visual Studio Code marketplace (*not* any of the Salesforce DX extension packs), and follow the instructions given in its [documentation](https://johnaaronnelson.gitbooks.io/forcecode/content/#configuration), starting with

> To begin, press Opt+Cmd+C or open the Command Pallet and type >ForceCode: Menu to bring up the ForceCode Menu